# How to calculate total price when product is added or reduced

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an e-commerce app. Currently, I'm creating add-to-cart `fragment`. So, I've managed to add the item to cart and display in `CartFragment`. But the problem is, when the quantity of a product is added and all products are checked, the total price changes to the total price for only the quantity of products added. When the quantity of all products is only one, the total price will count all the prices of the products in the checklist.

[image: 1]

Code for calculate prices :

```
final int total_all_price = totalPriceAll(productList);

// All checkboxes must be checked
holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
if (holder.checkBox.isChecked()) {
    int currentQty = dataItemCartList.get(position).getQuantity();

    if (currentQty > 0) {
        total_all_item += productList.get(position).getFinalPrice();
        listener.setTotalPrice(total_all_item * currentQty);
    }
}

// If user want to remove checklist in checkbox
holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (holder.checkBox.isChecked()) {
            int currentQty = dataItemCartList.get(position).getQuantity();
            int finalQty = currentQty + 1;

            dataItemCheckout.setCurrentPrice(dataItemCartList.get(position).getCurrentPrice());
            dataItemCheckout.setLastPrice(dataItemCartList.get(position).getLastPrice());
            dataItemCheckout.setQuantity(dataItemCartList.get(position).getQuantity());
            dataItemCheckout.setNotes(dataItemCartList.get(position).getNotes());

            dataItemCheckoutList.add(dataItemCheckout);

            productCheckout.setPriceAfterDiscount(productList.get(position).getPriceAfterDiscount());
            productCheckout.setPriceRegular(productList.get(position).getPriceRegular());

            productCheckoutList.add(productCheckout);

            total_all_item += productList.get(position).getFinalPrice();
            listener.onItemCheck(dataItemCart, productCart, dataItemCheckoutList, productCheckoutList);
            listener.setTotalPrice(total_all_item * currentQty);
        } else {                    
            int currentQty = dataItemCartList.get(position).getQuantity();
            int finalQty = currentQty - 1;

            dataItemCheckoutList.remove(dataItemCheckout);
            productCheckoutList.remove(productCheckout);

            total_all_item -= productList.get(position).getFinalPrice();
            listener.onItemUncheck(dataItemCart, productCart, dataItemCheckoutList, productCheckoutList);
            listener.setTotalPrice(total_all_item * currentQty);
        }
    }
});

private int totalPriceAll(List<Product> total_all) {
    int total_price_per_item = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < total_all.size(); i++) {
        total_price_per_item += total_all.get(i).getFinalPrice();
    }

    return total_price_per_item;
}

holder.btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (holder.checkBox.isChecked()) {
            int total_harga = productList.get(position).getFinalPrice();
            int currentQty = dataItemCartList.get(position).getQuantity();
            int finalQty = currentQty + 1;
            int finalPrice = finalQty * total_harga;

            dataItemCartList.get(position).setQuantity(finalQty);
            productList.get(position).setFinalPrice(finalPrice);
            listener.setTotalPrice(finalPrice);

            holder.tvQuantity.setText(finalQty + "");
        } else {
            int total_harga = productList.get(position).getFinalPrice();
            int currentQty = dataItemCartList.get(position).getQuantity();
            int finalQty = currentQty + 1;
            int finalPrice = finalQty * total_harga;

            dataItemCartList.get(position).setQuantity(finalQty);
            productList.get(position).setFinalPrice(finalPrice);

            holder.tvQuantity.setText(finalQty + "");
        }
    }
});
holder.btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (holder.checkBox.isChecked()) {
            int total_harga = productList.get(position).getFinalPrice();
            int currentQty = dataItemCartList.get(position).getQuantity();
            int finalQty = currentQty - 1;
            int finalPrice = finalQty * total_harga;

            if (finalQty < 1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Minimal satu item untuk pembelian", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                dataItemCartList.get(position).setQuantity(finalQty);
                productList.get(position).setFinalPrice(finalPrice);
                listener.setTotalPrice(finalPrice);

                holder.tvQuantity.setText(finalQty + "");
            }
        } else {
            int total_harga = productList.get(position).getFinalPrice();
            int currentQty = dataItemCartList.get(position).getQuantity();
            int finalQty = currentQty - 1;
            int finalPrice = finalQty * total_harga;

            if (finalQty < 1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Minimal satu item untuk pembelian", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                dataItemCartList.get(position).setQuantity(finalQty);
                productList.get(position).setFinalPrice(finalPrice);

                holder.tvQuantity.setText(finalQty + "");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please add code snippet of `setTotalPrice()` method? and also please clear where you call the `totalPriceAll()` method?

Comment: setTotalPrice just an interface, cause the text of total of price is outside recyclerview.

Comment: @Gowrishankar I have updated the code where I call the `totalPriceAll` method

Comment: please add a total adapter class file to find out the exact issue. And also `totalPriceAll` method needs to add all places like `setTotalPrice` since we need to update total prize too when the actions performed.